# Could not load file or assembly kre-clr-win - How can I specify the KRE?

Tags: asp.net, iis, clr, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to build my first application with ASP.NET 5 in the Visual Studio 2015 CTP.  I just published the app to the file system and copied the folder up to my AWS EC2 instance.  I setup the application in IIS so it points to the wwwroot directory from my published app.

I keep getting the Yellow Screen of Death (YSOD) when trying to run the app.  Looking at the Event Viewer, I can see an unhandled exception being thrown:

`Exception message: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\inetpub\wwwroot\appname\approot\packages\kre-clr-win-x64.1.0.0-beta3\bin\kre.clr.managed.dll' or one of its dependencies`

Sure enough, that file doesn't exist on disk.  It was never published with my application.  I do, however, have the x86 version: kre-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta3.  That directory was published with my app.

So for some reason my app is being published with kre-clr-win-x86, but when I try to run the published app it's looking for kre-clr-win-x64.  How do I fix this issue?

**Edit**

Here is the generated web.config in the published wwwroot folder:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="kpm-package-path" value="..\approot\packages" />
    <add key="bootstrapper-version" value="1.0.0-beta3" />
    <add key="runtime-path" value="..\approot\packages" />
    <add key="kre-version" value="1.0.0-beta3" />
    <add key="kre-clr" value="clr" />
    <add key="kre-app-base" value="..\approot\src\appname" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

**Edit 2**

As part of publishing a `web.cmd` file was generated (although I'm not sure what the file's particular use-case is) and if I run it the app gets served on localhost:5000.  If I visit the page locally, it works.  So it may be something related to the IIS pipeline?

Here's the full stack trace:

```
Exception information: 
    Exception type: FileNotFoundException 
    Exception message: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Gastropub\approot\packages\kre-clr-win-x64.1.0.0-beta3\bin\kre.clr.managed.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)    at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)    at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)    at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadFrom(String assemblyFile, Evidence securityEvidence, Byte[] hashValue, AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)    at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String assemblyFile, Evidence securityEvidence)    at System.Activator.CreateInstanceFromInternal(String assemblyFile, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo)    at System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceFrom(String assemblyFile, String typeName)    at System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceFrom(String assemblyFile, String typeName)    at AspNet.Loader.Bootstrapper.InitializeNet45(String runtimePackagePath, AppDomain targetDomain, String packagesDir, IObjectHandle& handle, String[]& args)    at AspNet.Loader.Bootstrapper.LoadApplicationNet45(String appId, String appConfigPath, IProcessHostSupportFunctions supportFunctions, LoadApplicationData* pLoadAppData, Int32 loadAppDataSize, String runtimePackagePath, String appBasePath)    at AspNet.Loader.Bootstrapper.LoadApplication(String appId, String appConfigPath, IProcessHostSupportFunctions supportFunctions, LoadApplicationData* pLoadAppData, Int32 loadAppDataSize)    at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)    at System.Web.Hosting.ProcessHost.System.Web.Hosting.IProcessHostLite.ReportCustomLoaderError(String appId, Int32 hr, AppDomain newlyCreatedAppDomain)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateAppDomainWithHostingEnvironment(String appId, IApplicationHost appHost, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.HostingInit(HostingEnvironmentFlags hostingFlags, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException)
```

Comment: Have you installed K on the amazon box?

Comment: I have.  Although it's looking for a particular directory as part of my application package, so it doesn't seem like it's a system dependency issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you are deploying the application on a 64 bit OS, you need to use the 64 bit KLR.

This is how you bundle an application with the KLR:

```
kpm bundle --runtime kre-clr-win-x64.1.0.0-beta3
```

That will produce a folder that contains your application, its dependencies and the CLR. Just copy to the webserver and you should be good to go.